# jQuery datetimepicker limits selectable dates to end of current year

Tags: jquery, regex, date

I have recently taken over the development of some software that has been written in Python/ Django.

A form on one of the pages on the website allows users to enter a date/ time using a jQuery `datetimepicker`, and there is an issue with this, that range of dates available for selection is limited to dates between the beginning of the previous year up to the end of the current year (i.e. dates currently available are between 01/01/2016- 31/12/2017).

While this is not currently an issue, it did cause some issues towards the end of last year, when my colleagues wanted to schedule meetings for the beginning of this year, but weren't able to as dates beyond 31/12/2016 were not able to be selected.

I created a temporary fix for this at the time by allowing users to manually type in the dates/ times that they wanted to schedule meetings for.

Now, after the new year, the dates available for selection in this field is limited to 01/01/2016- 31/12/2017, whereas up until the end of last year the dates available were 01/01/2015- 31/12/2016.

So it appears that the values are being restricted to dates between the beginning of the previous year and end of current year. I now want to extend the range of dates available so that all dates between the beginning of the previous year and end of the following year (relevant to the current date) are available for selection.

Having searched the `jquery.datetimepicker.full.js` file where this `datetimepicker` is defined, I have found the following relevant parts of the code:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker = function (opt, opt2) {
    ...
    createDateTimePicker = function (input) {
        ...
        datetimepicker.setOptions = function (_options) {
            var highlightedDates = {};
            options = $.extend(true, {}, options, _options);
            ...
            if(_options.allowDates && $.isArray(_options.allowDates && _options.allowDates.length) {
                options.allowDates = $.extend(true, [], _options.allowDates);
            }
            if(_options.allowDateRe && Object.prototype.toString.call(_options.allowDateRe)=="[object String]") {
                options.allowDateRe = new RegExp(_options.allowDateRe);
            }
            ...
            if(options.minDate && /^[\+\-](.*)$/.test(options.minDate)){
                options.minDate = dateHelper.formatDate(_xdsoft_datetime.strToDateTime(options.minDate), options.formatDate);
            }
            if(options.maxDate && /^[\+\-](.*)$/.test(options.maxDate)){
                options.maxDate = dateHelper.formatDate(_xdsoft_datetime.strToDateTime(options.maxDate), options.formatDate);
            }
            ...
        };
        ...
        XDSoft_datetime = function () {
            ...
            _this.setCurrentTime = function(dTime) {
                _this.currentTime = (typeof dTime === 'string') ? _this.strToDateTime(dTime) : _this.isValidDate(dTime)) ? dTime : _this.now();
                datetimepicker.trigger('xchange.xdsoft');
            });
            ...
            _this.getCurrentTime = function(dTime){
                return _this.currentTime);
            };
            ...
        };
        ...
        mounth_picker
            ...
            .on('touchend mousedown.xdsoft', function(){
                ...
            }).on('dblclick.xdsoft', function(){
                var currentDate = _xdsoft_datetime.getCurrentTime(), minDate, maxDate;
                currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate());
                minDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strToDate(options.minDate);
                minDate = new Date(minDate.getFullYear(), minDate.getMonth(), minDate.getDate());
                if(currentDate < minDate){
                    return;
                }
                maxDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strToDate(optioins.maxDate);
                maxDate = new Date(maxDate.getFullYear(), maxDate.getMonth(), maxDate.getDate());
                if(currentDate > maxDate){
                    return;
                }
                ...
            });
        mounth_picker
            ...
            .on('touchend mousedown.xdsoft', function(){
                ...
                (function arguments_called(v) {
                    ...
                }(500));
                ...
            });
        ...
        datetimepicker
            .on('xchange.xdsoft', function (event) {
                clearTimeout(xchangeTimer);
                xchangeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    ...
                    var table = '',
                        ...
                        maxDate = false,
                        minDate = false,
                        ...
                    ...
                    if (options.maxDate !== false){
                        maxDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strToDate(options.maxDate);
                        maxDate = new Date(maxDate.getFullYear(), maxDate.getMonth(), maxDate.getDate(), 23, 59, 59, 999);
                    }
                    ...
                    while(i < _xdsoft_datetime.currentTime.countDaysInMonth() || start.getDay() !== options.dayOfWeekStart || _xdsoft_datetime.currentTime.getMonth() === start.getMonth()) {
                        ...
                        d = start.getDate();
                        y = start.getFullYear();
                        m = start.getMonth();
                        ...
                        if(options.allowDateRe && Object.prototype.toString.call(options.allowDateRe) === "[object RegExp]"){
                            if(!options.allowDateRe.test(dateHelper.formatDate(start, options.formatDate))){
                                classes.push('xdsoft_disabled');
                            }
                        } else if(options.allowDates && options.allowDates.length>0){
                            if(options.allowDates.indexOf(dateHelper.formatDate(start, options.formatDate)) === -1){
                                classes.push('xdsoft_disabled');
                            }
                        } else if ((maxDate !== false && start > maxDate) || (minDate !== false && start < minDate) || (customDateSettings && customDateSettings[0] === false)) {
                            classes.push('xdsoft_disabled');
                        } else if (options.disabledDates.indexOf(dateHelper.formatDate(start, options.formatDate)) !== -1) {
                            classes.push('xdsoft_disabled');
                        } else if (options.disabledWeekDays.indexOf(day) !== -1) {
                            classes.push('xdsoft_disabled');
                        }else if (input.is('[readonly]')) {
                            classes.push('xdsoft_disabled');
                        }
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
                }, 10);
                ...
            })
            ...
            });
        ...
        };
        ...
    };
    ...
    return result;
};
```

I can see that the `maxDate` is being set to a regular expression, but can't see how/ where it is actually given a value/ set to the end of the current year, unless it's on the lines:

```
maxDate = _xdsoft_datetime.strToDate(optioins.maxDate);
maxDate = new Date(maxDate.getFullYear(), maxDate.getMonth(), maxDate.getDate());
```

If so, how can I set this to be the end of the following year (relevant to the current year), rather than being the end of the current year- which is what it seems to be at the moment?

Or if this isn't what's restricting the `maxDate` to the end of the current year, what is, and how can I change it to be the end of next year (always relevant to the current year)?

**Edit**

The `datetimepicker` is displayed as a widget on a form in the HTML using the following Django code:

```
<td colspan="6">
    {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
        {% if field.name == 'presentation_date' %}
            {% with presentation_form.instance.meeting as meeting %}
                {% include "projects/includes/meeting_bit.html" with employee=request.user.employee meeting=meeting UID=presentation_form.instance.id %}
            {% endwith %}
            {# <a class="ical_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'events:add_to_cal' %}" {% if not field.value %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>Add to calendar</a> #}
        {% else %}
            {{field}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

and the `meeting_bit.html` file that it uses is defined with:

```
{% if meeting and meeting.event_creator and meeting.event_creator != employee %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{meeting.date|date:"d/m/Y H:i"}}<br>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2"><a class="change_event_organiser" data-view-url="{% url 'events:change_event_creator' meeting.id %}" class="button">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-sm">
                Organised by {{meeting.event_creator}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{% else %}

    <div id="cal_{{field.name}}_{{UID}}">
        {{field}}
        <a class="ical_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'events:add_to_cal' %}" {% if not field.value %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
        {% if meeting.event_id %}Update calendar event{% else %}Add to calendar{% endif %}
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: removed `python` and `django` tags, as it seems to be purely a jquery problem.

Comment: The code you're looking at is the plugin's code. You need to look somewhere else for code that looks like one of these [examples](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).

Comment: None of my code looks like that- the `widget` is displayed as part of a Django form, so I don't know how I'd set a `startDate` or `endDate` from within this...? I'll update my OP now to show how the widget is displayed.

Comment: Code for how/ where the `widget` is displayed added.

Comment: Inspect the date-time input, what class(es) and id it has?